# checking ruggability of a token

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some python code to check the safety of a token - I'm trying to access things like the isMutable in the metadata, work out if it's still mintable, and eventually check if LP is locked etc. I've been banging my head against a wall with solana-py - can anyone point me in the right direction, I don't seem to be able to get anything useful back from solana to delve deeper into parameters from the token address.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tested it, but it might look a little something like this. Just an idea to get your juices flowing.

```
    import requests
import base64
from solana.rpc.api import Client

def main():
    # Initialize Solana RPC client
    client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

    # Specify the token address
    token_address = "INSERT_YOUR_TOKEN_ADDRESS_HERE"

    # Fetch and decode token metadata
    metadata = fetch_token_metadata(client, token_address)

    # Analyze token properties
    if metadata:
        is_mutable = check_mutability(metadata)
        is_mintable = check_mintability(metadata)

        # Display results
        print(f"Token Mutable: {is_mutable}")
        print(f"Token Mintable: {is_mintable}")
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch token metadata.")

def fetch_token_metadata(client, token_address):
    # Get account info
    response = client.get_account_info(token_address)
    if response['result']['value'] is None:
        return None

    # Decode the metadata account data
    data = response['result']['value']['data'][0]
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    
    # TODO: Add additional parsing of decoded_data to extract the metadata
    # This depends on the structure of your token's metadata

    return decoded_data

def check_mutability(metadata):
    # Logic to determine mutability from metadata
    # Placeholder: Replace with your actual logic
    return "Mutable" in metadata

def check_mintability(metadata):
    # Logic to determine mintability from metadata
    # Placeholder: Replace with your actual logic
    return "Mintable" in metadata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you write this with ChatGPT

Comment: I asked ChatGPT to provide an outline of how it would be done and then filled in the logic.

Comment: You didn't fill in the logic